# CentOS7 sudo yum install forever says "No package forever available"

Tags: node.js, centos, forever

my CentOS7 will not "sudo yum install forever" - gives error: "No package forever available". so i tried

```
"sudo -u [appuser] nohup node [path_to_your_app] > [path_to_log_file] 2>&1 &", where;

[appuser] = admin
[path_to_your_app] = server.js
[path_to_log_file] = log.txt.
```

still, in 5 min the sever timed out due to "broken pipe" and web page running via node server, stopped.

ideas?

Comment: why would someone downvote this question? i proofread the question and that is exactly what happens. yet seems like every response via google says simply install "forever". ideas why forever is not found?::
1-[admin@centos7 ~]$ sudo yum install forever;
2-Loaded plugins: fastestmirror;
3-Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
4- * base: mirror.keystealth.org
5- * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
6- * extras: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
7-* updates: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
8- No package forever available.
9-Error: Nothing to do
10- [admin@centos7 ~]$

Answer (score 4):

If you have nodejs and npm installed on CentOS, you should be able to install forever by calling:

```
npm install forever -g
```

If nodejs and npm is not installed, please do following:

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs
```

All the commands are to be called with sudo...

Answer (score 0):

read somewhere that CentOS uses yum, not npm; but i got npm installed, forever downloaded; but "[forever] command not found" at this point. trying to move on, checking out pm2.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it's still not answered sufficiently to solve my specific issue, and perhaps yours. I had the same issue.

Short answer: 
    1. sudo yum install "*forever*" 
    2. install node if needed
    3. sudo npm install forever -g
    4. look for output for where forever is stored
    5. create a symbolic link in your path

Using Centos 7. Here was my method, hopefully this helps.

What did not work initially:

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

My issue was that I needed to issue this pay key attention tot the " and * characters:

```
sudo yum install "*forever*"
```

My missing dependencies appeared to have nothing to do with forever. This approach is overly broad, but can be refined to add only the missing dependency, or with trial and error, this can be refeind. There was the list and the install:

```
Installed:
  qt3-devel.x86_64 0:3.3.8b-51.el7                                                                      
  qt3-devel-docs.x86_64 0:3.3.8b-51.el7                                                                     

Dependency Installed:
  libjpeg-turbo-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.90-6.el7                                    
  libmng-devel.x86_64 0:1.0.10-14.el7                                    
  qt3.x86_64 0:3.3.8b-51.el7                                   

Dependency Updated:
  libjpeg-turbo.x86_64 0:1.2.90-6.el7
```

After that I again performed the npm install:

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

The results this time yeilded (among other things):

/opt/node_packaging/node-v10.15.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever

Still the forever command did not work, however executing this at the cli did!

So a quick command to fix this from the cli:
    1) copy it to /usr/bin: sudo cp /opt/node_packaging/node-v10.15.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever /usr/bin
    or
    2) create a symbolic link: sudo ln -s /opt/node_packaging/node-v10.15.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever /usr/bin/forever

I did the later, chosing to do a symbolic link.

It works!

```
$ forever
help:    usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]
help:    
help:    Monitors the script specified in the current process or as a daemon
etc.
```